# Can´t find my code in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code that should run when a cell in the worksheet changes. It works well and fast.

Now I want to add another case to the code... but now I can´t find it.

Can I somehow search for the code? There are no modules or forms and I have tried to select worksheet and change.. but the code does not appear.

Please help

Regards
Henrik

Comment: Funny...:-)

I can only see my 3 command buttons with the code... so I´m looking for a possibility to show all active codes in an worksheet

Comment: Right-click worksheet name tab, View Code.

Comment: I have tried that. It only shows my 3 command buttons

Comment: If not in the worksheet's private code sheet, then ctrl+R to show the Project Explorer and double-click ThisWorkbook. Look for Workbook_SheetChange.

Comment: Those are he only two places that make sense but you can ctrl+F, look for some bit of code you remember then Entire Project.

Comment: Been there too.. it shows only an empty code sheet..

Comment: Is it recorded code?  That can end up in the `PERSONAL.XLSB` if _Personal Macro Workbook_ was selected on the dialog box.  Saying that - if it was recorded it wouldn't be in Change event code.

Comment: It´s not recorded.

The code you get when record is not very good and fast. Learned that when reading through many posts here.

I know I have used select case formula.. but it wont find it with CTRL+F

Comment: Might you have put the code in a XLAM file (and add-in)? Or have you done anything with VSTO or another kind of COM add-in? If you look in File/Options/Add-ins do you see anything in that list that looks familiar? Or in Developer/Add-ins?

Comment: To add a screenshot (or any other additional information) to a Question: click the [edit] tab under the question. In the toolbar at the top there's an icon for inserting pictures (7th from the left). Since you're new, you can only insert the link, but others can bring in the full picture.

Comment: As I don't  use add ins in Excel and just used the normal Excel VBA editor 

I hava tried to select all possibilities  (General/Workbook/ Sheet1 ...)

But no code appears only my 3 command buttons

https://imageshack.com/i/pnY07nyjj

Comment: What other code are you expecting - that image (sorry, can't put into main question) is showing the code behind the command buttons.  The code appears to be in `Ark1`.

Comment: I have written a code that changes the color of the cell depending which name I use.

I have used the Select Case formula to solve this. It´s working in ARK1 as it should. Now I Need to add another case. But can´t find the code

Comment: Sorry - ignore that last comment.  You're looking for the change event code that you've written in that worksheet..... did you close the workbook without saving?  Sounds obvious, but I've done it plenty of times myself.... but saying that you say the first case is working on the change event?  I'm stumped...

Comment: No problem...
Closing without saving....Never did that :-)  Happens many times for me too..

The code is working, so it must be somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If the code reacts on Worksheet change, it's within `Microsoft Excel Objects` for the sheet 
[image]

Comment: But there *must* be the part with the Excel Objects? Can you show a PrintScreen Image of the *Project Explorer*?

Comment: Sorry can´t see how to add an screenshot.. (Newbee) 

I have the Excel object where my 3 sheets are shown and This workbook

Comment: Have you clicked on the sheet object (for the sheet where the `change` is running) ? It should contain the code.

Comment: Click on the left dropdown box above your code (where it shows `CommandButton3`) and select `Worksheet`

Comment: It´s running on ARK1 Prodplan. I have clicked it voew code... but only my buttons appear.

I have tried to select Worksheet and then every other possibility going from Activate to Select change.

Can I somehow stop a code from being executed and find it with debug?

Comment: One last idea: Have you checked the code on `Workbook`-Level - event there is `Workbook_SheetChange`. If that doesn't work: Try to export your code via `VBE`, example: https://gist.github.com/steve-jansen/7589478

Comment: I have tried both... and the export doesn´t show the code I´m looking for... weired because it´s working, so it must be somewhere.

Thx for trying.

Comment: Just saw your comment below the original question:  You haven't done this via Conditional Formatting ?

Comment: 100% it was too slow, that´s why I wanted to code it.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsJtGOUIRp-WgvlmV6xiiPc7aiD6YA

Link to my file... if that helps

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will help, but when my code hides (hugely frustrating!), I hit the "Macros" button - it should show up in the list there if it's working in your sheet.  Then you can select it, choose "step into", and at least get to where you can edit the code. Good luck!

Comment: As is obvious from the problem description as well as the discussion, the code in question is an *event handler*. Those are *never* listed under "Macros" because they're not public subs with no arguments. They're private and have arguments.